# Ignoring some file when ziping them

Tags: vb.net, zip

i use dotnetZip in my progect ,i want when i compress folder , some file(like .jpg or foldername or filename) not compress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
    zip.AddSelectedFiles("name != folder1\*.jpg", "folder1", true);
    zip.Save(_zipFileName);
```